How can I solve a simple beam problem?
I had to find the safety factor of a beam that is compressed by a force. In particular, is a simple beam with this section: 
it is 3.7 m long. I used a FEM software to find the s.f and it results that on the walls the s.f is 1.12 (if I put a weight of 8850 N at the top of the beam).
I try always to interpret the results and it seem strange that that pillar can sustain ONLY 900 kg .  In your opinion, is a likely value? (the material is: structural steel). I know that exists Euler critical load. Is Euler critical load theory compatible with those results ?

Did you use static analysis or eigen buckling analysis? The latter could be comparable with Euler beam buckling, but there might even be buckling of the section walls at smaller loads..

i used static analysis

Did you also try to calculate the safety factor yourself? It should be very simple in this case, just using the load, cross section area and allowable stress.
